# Anonymous function consuming another anonymous function - clojure koan

Tags: clojure

I am working on the clojure koans and one of the questions in the functions needs further explanation for me to “get it” and have an aha moment. I am able to write the function that satisfies the question. But I don't fully understand why all the bits work.

```
Clojure> (= 25 ((fn [a b] (b a)) 5 (fn [n] (* n n))))
true
```

**Question 1.**
I do not understand why this throws an error:

```
Clojure> (= 25 ((fn [b a] (b a)) 5 (fn [n] (* n n))))
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

So the only change in the above is switching the order of b and a.
In my brain I read “a function that takes an a and b” or a “b and an a” but how they are used is up to the subsequent statement in the parens. Why does the order matter at this point?

**Questions 2.**

```
Clojure> (= 25 ((fn [a] (5 a)) (fn [n] (* n n))))
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Why when I substitute out the value of b for the int it represents do I get an error?

**Quentions 3.**

```
((fn [a b] (b a)) 5 (fn [n] (* n n))))
```

Why does this not throw an error (b a) b in this instance is 5 which is a symbol.
The first item in brackets is expected to be a function or a special form unless it is a list?

Comment: [Koans on github](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/src/koans/functions.clj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. look at your expression in the first function:

   ```
   (b a)
   ```

   since `b` is first, `b` has to be a function.  In your second example, you're trying to pass 5 to `b`, but 5 is not a function.  With descriptive names you can see that you're trying to use 5 as a function:

   ```
   ((fn [argument function] (argument function)) ;; problem!!
    5 
    (fn [n] (* n n)))
   ```

   Remember the evaluation rules for lisps:  given this s-expression:

   ```
   (f x y z)
   ```

   evaluate f, x, y, and z, and apply f as a function to x, y, and z.
2. see answer to 1 -- '5' is not a function.  Use descriptive names, and easily spot the problem:

   ```
   ((fn [function] (5 function)) ;; problem!!
    (fn [n] (* n n)))
   ```

   Change to:

   ```
      ((fn [a] (a 5))  ;; 'a' and '5' flipped
       (fn [n] (* n n)))
   ```

   to get this to run.
3. this isn't a problem:  `a` is 5, `b` is a function in `(b a)`.  With descriptive names it makes more sense:

   ```
   ((fn [argument function] (function argument)) 
    5
    (fn [n] (* n n)))
   ```